# Grails dependencies can't be resolved due to project not compiling

Tags: grails, groovy, upgrade

I'm in the process of upgrading a grails project from 1.3.6 to 2.2.4.  I'm currently having an issue where dependencies can't be resolved.  The problems tab in Groovy Grails Tool Suite shows `The type groovy.lang.GroovyObject cannot be resolved...`.

When I run grails refresh-dependencies, it says that dependencies are refreshed.  However, when I right click on the project and select `Grails Tools -> Refresh dependencies`, the process fails with the following

```
 Loading Grails 2.2.4
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Compiling 600 source files
| Warning The [generatePublishingEmail] action accepts a parameter of type [java.util.List] which has not been marked with @Validateable.  Data binding will still be applied to this command object but the instance will not be validateable.
def generatePublishingEmail(def subject, def releaseNumber, List components, def notes, def publishType, String email, def productName)
^
| Compiling 600 source files.
| Error Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: Compilation Failed (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException
...
```

To be sure that groovy could be resolved, I created a sample project in grails 2.2.4.  This compiled fine and resolved dependencies without any issues.  Also, I turned the BuildConfig.groovy logging level to debug, but that provided little help.

Comment: Have you checked and updated all the build dependency and plugin versions in BuildConfig.groovy?  Have a look at the BuildConfig.groovy  in your sample project, and make sure things like tomcat/hibernate/etc are right?

Comment: All take a look.  Is the `application.properties` file completely deprecated now?  Previously that was all that was used to manage which version of tomcat/hibernate we were using.

Comment: Yeah, `application.properties` is just there for grails and app versions afaik...  Also, `grails clean` might help?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I generally do a grails clean before refreshing dependencies.  I've also completely nuked the .grails directory contents.

Comment: Any idea on how to stacktrace the refresh dependencies command under grails tools?

Comment: I usually just nuke the target folder from the command line..  It does sound like something that has changed in BuildConfig.groovy though, 1.3.6->2.2.4 is quite a big jump, so some node or property might have changed name

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40651/discussion-between-joseph-and-tim-yates)

Comment: It looks like the Warning being printed was actually causing issues.  I fixed the warning, then got an OOM exception.  I added more memory and am now getting proper messages so I can fix the compiler problems.